# NDSolve::depdole error

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a pair of differential equations with `NDSolve`.  They contain a discontinuous function `bounce`. I've trimmed down my original equations to the following for simplicity:

```
eqxy = {
  0.1 == bounce[x[t]] - Cos[x[t]] x''[t], 
  y''[t] == -Sin[x[t]] + Cos[x[t]] x''[t]
};
```

where

```
bounce[x_] := If[Abs[x] >= 0.045, Abs[x], 0]
```

The following formatting may be clearer
$$
\left(
\begin{align}
 0.1 &=\text{If}\,[\left| x(t)\right| \geq 0.045,\,\left| x(t)\right|,\,0]-x''(t) \cos(x(t)) \cr
 y''(t) &=x''(t) \cos (x(t))-\sin (x(t)) \cr
\end{align}
\right)
$$

Now, running

```
NDSolve[
  Join[eqxy, {x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 1}], 
  {x, y}, {t, 0, 1}, Method -> "Automatic"]
```

yields the error message

> NDSolve::depdole: The differential order of a dependent variable in {x'[t], x''[t], y'[t], y''[t]} exceeds the highest order that appears in the differential equations.

although interpolating functions are produced as solutions.

The error seems to be associated with `bounce`, with its conditional and absolute value functions -- removing `bounce` eliminates the error message. But how does `bounce` cause any order excess?

Appreciate any insights.  (Hope I've eliminated any typos.)

I'm running Mathematica version 10.3.0.0, Linux x86 (64-bit).

Comment: I did not get this error when I ran your code. It actually worked fine. Quit the kernel and try again. (However, if I extended the time limit past 1.2, you get a numerical stiffness error, so you have some work to do to make it numerically tractable.)

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error with V10.3 running on OS X 10.10.2.

Comment: Thanks.  I added my version & platform above.  By the way, I've quit and restarted the kernel multiple times.  I did move over to v10.1, on Windows 8.1, and quit getting the error.  (But I do still have more work to do, to be sure.)

Comment: The message also goes away if you use `bounce[x_?NumericQ]`. I think `NDSolve` gets confused during the derivative estimation. You could report this to the wolfram support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [confirmed bug in event processing](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/762249).

Try `Method -> {Automatic, "DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}` as a workaround.

```
NDSolve[
  Join[eqxy, {x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 1}], 
  {x, y}, {t, 0, 1}, Method -> {Automatic, "DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}]
```